# Load original email content via hook_mail_alter()

Tags: 8, emails

I'm hooking into `hook_mail_alter()` to make an amendment to outgoing emails before they go, but by the time they are loaded by `hook_mail_alter()`, any token has already been replaced.

Is it possible to use any of the information from the email to retrieve the original "tokenized" version so that I can pass those separately?

Comment: By "original" content, you mean "the raw value before any token replacement has occurred"?

Comment: How is the email being generated? What triggers it?

Comment: @PatrickKenny, yes basically

Comment: @Jaypan, unfortunately, I'm trying to make a catchment for potentially any module that could, that's why at the moment I'm using `hook_mail_alter` instead of trying to track down a possible function that initiates it. The reason is that I am trying to build a module that could be used by any number of our sites, and could have multiple different methods to send emails, so I'm trying to see if I can make a catch-all